# Can a template be modified and all the subsites that are using it have the changes?

Tags: site-template, sub-site

I'm new on SharePoint and I would like to know if having a template for my subsites, in the case I modify my template all the subsites that are using that template should be affected with the changes.

I would like to have a template that I can modify and all my pages have those changes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your old sites will not be updated once the site template is updated. But you can create a feature with all your changes and update the site template. After that you can run a powershell script to activate the new feature in all your old sites.

Comment: First at all, thanks for your kind response. Only one more question, then a template on Share Point is just used to base a new site using that template, is that all that you can get from a template? I thought a template can be used as a base part of any site, and then modifying it my pages using a template could be modified also...

Comment: Yes. That's right. Template is just a collection of artifacts that defines your site in one package. Once a site is created based on that, the new site will have it's own copy of those artifacts. Hence, modifying those artifacts of the template will not affect the already created site.